# How does JVM ensures fixed size of the data types across different types of platforms?

Tags: java, jvm

Like how does JVM ensures the same size of data types among 32 and 64 bit system. If someone can explain in some detail it will be helpful.

Comment: On 64-bit machines, it uses 32-bit references where possible, however, if it has to use a 64-bit reference the data structures won't be the same size. Primitives are the same size by definition.

Comment: The real question is why a given primitive isn't the same size across platforms in other languages? The language doesn't define the size and it is left to the implementer to decide.

Answer (score 0):

The Java Language Spec (JLS) specifies the storage requirements for each primitive type.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html

For example:

> The integral types are byte, short, int, and long, whose values are 8-bit, 16-bit, 32-bit and 64-bit signed two's-complement integers, respectively.

Therefore all JVMs will use these sizes for the various primitive types.

32 vs 64-bit doesn't change the data storage for primitives, just how much memory can be addressed:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/17287289/657224