# Processing Sketch- Why is 32-bit and 64-bit both created?

Tags: java, compilation, processing

I've recently been experimenting with Processing  (https://processing.org/).

It's a sort of IDE used to make GUI design in Java easier. Since I'm not a fan of swing or AWT, I found it quite fun to use.

Something interesting to note though. When I "export" the Application for windows, it creates both a 32-bit and 64-bit version.

I'm a little confused as I thought after Java source code is compiled to Java bytecode, it can be run anywhere as long as that place as a JVM. (Write once, run anywhere).

So why are both a 32 bit and 64 bit version of the app created? Shouldn't the bytecode be platform independent and only be translated using Just-In-Time compilation to whichever architecture the JVM is on, during runtime? At least, I know that's how .NET does it with the CLR.

I'm going to attempt to answer my own question by saying since the applications created are .exe files, the translation to native architecture happened ALREADY, since windows was specified as a target-platform...I guess to increase efficiency?

Otherwise, I'm confused. The only time I've seen a compilation happen twice is when I was programming C++, and needed to compile twice for 32-bit and 64-bit.

Thank you!

Comment: I'd read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17285928/jre-32bit-vs-64bit

Comment: Still a bit confused. That's explaining the difference between JVM 32-bit and 64-bit. I know there's both JVMS, that's fine. The confusion is why there are two output compiled files. Thought the JVM translated using JIT compilation, and since the JVM is dependant, the compliation wouldn't be.

Comment: Most likely because the stuff that is generated when you "export" includes a native code launcher, a native code library, or a dependency on a native code library.  Or a combination of the above, based on what I have read.

Comment: My guess: processing is end-user oriented. They try to make it as simple as possible to the designer. For a Windows user, running an .exe is a lot easier than having to install Java and run a jar file.

Answer (score 1):

Processing is built on top of [JOGL](http://jogamp.org/jogl/www/) which is (basically) a Java wrapper of [OpenGL](https://www.opengl.org/), which is a device-specific graphics library.

Also, Processing (can) include a whole JVM with its exported applications, so end users don't have to worry about downloading Java. The JVM itself is OS-dependent, so the exported application is as well.

You can confirm this by taking a look at the files that Processing creates. Specifically, notice these files:

- `jogl-rt-natives-windows-amd64.jar`
- `jogl-all-natives-windows-amd64.jar`

These `.jar` files contain the native files required by JOGL.

Comment: Okay. I sort of get it. But I actually opted out of including the JVM as part of the exported application. Wouldn't that mean the app is just java byte code to be interpreted by the JVM that the user has? In which case, there shouldn't need to be a 32-bit and 64-bit version. Unless there's two versions of java byte code

Comment: @user3923150 The JVM is only a small part of my answer. The rest of it is talking about JOGL, which requires OS-specific native libraries.

Comment: OHHH. So JOGL is not actually compiled to byte code then. It's just wrapped in Java. The java portion of the app is only converted to byte code.

Comment: @user3923150 JOGL contains Java code that is compiled to byte code, and it also contains native libraries. You can look inside the `.jar` files to see exactly what those files are if you're curious.