# Java Number Format Exception in Conversion from String to Integer

Tags: java, string, int, number-formatting, numberformatexception

The following program Generate Unique key by using Date and Time(using joda time API)

```
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;
import org.joda.time.*;

public class EnDecoding {


    public String EncodeRecieverAddress(String emailaddress){
        byte[] encodedBytes = Base64.encodeBase64(emailaddress.getBytes());
        return new String(encodedBytes);
    }

    public String DecodeRecieverAddress(String encodedemail){
        byte[] decodedBytes = Base64.decodeBase64(encodedemail.getBytes());
        return new String(decodedBytes);
    }

    public int GenerateUniquekey() {
        LocalTime localtime = new LocalTime();
        LocalDate localdate = new LocalDate();
        String  key = "" + localdate.getDayOfYear()   
                    + localdate.getDayOfMonth()
                    + localdate.getDayOfWeek()
                    + localtime.getHourOfDay()
                    + localtime.getMinuteOfHour()
                    + localtime.getSecondOfMinute()
                    + localtime.getMillisOfSecond();
        System.out.println(key);
        System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(key.trim()));
      return 0;
    }
}
```

> System.out.println(key);

Output : 117275232750437

> System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(key.trim()));

java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "117275232750437"

I have used id.trim() function to eliminates leading and trailing spaces , but that does not solve my problem too.

Please dont mark this question duplicate as because other similar kind of questions didnt help me much that's why i have created this new question and so I hope to get the best answer over here.

Comment: It's too large to be stored as an Integer

Comment: but it also gave me same error when i stored it on long datatype variable

Comment: Worked fine for me with Long.

Comment: It’s quite a peculiar way to generate a supposedly unique key. For something simpler and more standard I suggest [`UUID`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html) or [`System.currentTimeMillis()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis--) or just an ever incrementing counter.

Comment: It’s not a question of *storing* it in a `long`, @burhanuddinabbas. You need to use `Long.parseLong()` too.

Comment: How unique are your keys going to be? As far as I can tell, Monday Jan 1, 2018, 02:16:19.500, and Saturday Apr 21, 2018, 19:05:00.000 will both give the key 11121619500. There will be many more clashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maximum value of integer is 2,147,483,647, your input is too large. Use `Long` instead.

Comment: i have already tried Long datatype , it gave me same exception

Comment: `Long.parseLong("117275232750437")` seems to be working just fine for me. Are you sure this is the exact content of the string you're trying to parse?

Comment: Thanks , my problem is solved now . By the way , does the range of datatypes depends on  processor architectures like 32 bit or 64 bit ?

Comment: Great, glad your problem is resolved, please mark an answer if it did help you, so that others see that this question is answered. And concerning processor architecture - the data ranges are the same for primitives on both 32 and 64 bit, some interesting thoughts are made on atomicity of the operations here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/9511836/5362510

Comment: A Java `int` is 32 bits no matter the processor it is running on. Similarly a `long` is always 64 bits independently of the underlying processor.

Answer (score 2):

Use `Long` instead of Integer as it is out of range of `Integer`

```
  String s = "117275232750437";
  System.out.println(Long.parseLong(s));
```

- Integer range : -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647
- Long range : -9,223,372,036,854,775,808 to 9,223,372,036,854,775,807

Comment: Great!!! Happy to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Your number is too much large, you should use a `Long`.
Maximum value of `int` are 2.147.483.647.